Go Fuzzing output on non failing test cases
I want to be able to see all of the fuzzed inputs to the function that is being tested.
So far I have tried using t.Log(...) t.Error(...) t.Fail(...)... none of those gave me the result that I wanted.
I would like to see input parameters on both failing, and non-failing tests.
Why do I need this? Lets say I have a function that is parsing input and populating struct fields. One of those fields has specific constraints, lets say somethin like 123 < filed < 321. Suppose I forgot to implement that constraint in the function that is being tested - therefore i would like to be reminded by fuzzed input that it could perhaps be less than 123 or greater than 321 (which should fail/return error... something like that)..
func FuzzF(f *testing.F) {
    f.Fuzz(func(t *testing.T, a float64){
        t.Log("A: ", a)
    })
}

